# Different Background Images For Each List Item Navigation?

Tags: html, css

I would like to use images for navigation names and change the image for each menu item on hover. What is the best approach for doing this? An example would be great. Each list item would have it's own image for normal, active and mouse over.

I'm trying to make the menu names look like they are being pushed in on mouse over.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please read the [faq]. What have you tried so far? What went wrong? What do you think the next step is? If you can't answer these questions, we can't help with yours.

Comment: I have tried the traditional change background image. That won't work because each list item has it's own image.

Comment: Post some code for what you've tried, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) may be helpful.

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: traditional? Please show how you did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6nFJ/) rigged up for you. It involves the background-image property and the :hover and :active css selectors. You can read up on those [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

It's recommended for this though that you read up on [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) instead of using individual images though, for performance reasons.

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to do with css, just put :hover after the element you want to change.
I did a very quick example without trying the code, so I'm sorry if it doesn't work, but you get the drift.

The HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="link1"><a>Link 1</a></li>
<li class="link2"><a>Link 2</a></li>
<ul>
```

The CSS:

```
li.link1 {
background: url('img/link1_normal.png');
}

li.link1:hover {
background: url('img/link1_hover.png');
}


li.link2 {
background: url('img/link2_normal.png');
}

li.link2:hover {
background: url('img/link2_hover.png');
}
```

Comment: I know, but whats the point of overcomplicating things for a guy that doesn't even know how to use the simplest css technique? Everything has its place and time.

Comment: @hustlerinc I would have thanked you and also give you credit but since you're set on being a jerk and making comments as you did, I won't.

Comment: @Ibanez, It is important to keep your ego in check while learning on [SO]. Given your question, you are a beginner. There was a time when I didn't know how to use the simplest CSS technique. Experts were beginners once too.

Comment: Ego has nothing to do with it. Unnecessary comments do though.

Comment: @Ibanez it wasn't meant to insult you... I'm sorry if it offended you. All I said was it would've been too much information given your knowledge.

Comment: The thing is I was already using sprites. What you gave me helped but I am trying to make it look more natural when swapping images. I want to fade out the first image and fade in the second. Using sprites and css to move the position shows an up/down when transitioning. Your comment about my lake of knowledge didn't add to the post. If I had the knowledge then there would be no point in me posting.